# Easier way to handle so many isnull() situation

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, null

Is there any good way to avoid writing `isnull()` function so many times inside a stored procedure?

I have a stored procedure that uses the `isnull()` function almost 30 times, I think that I am missing a concept, but until I find better way to get my data I'll love to clean my code from so many `isnull()` functions.

Can I for while set SQL Server 2008 R2 to using null values as float 0? Most of my `isnull()` is just adding zero 0 value if there is no data so I can do math operations.

EDIT: I am not lazy, I just trying to clean my code and avoid select parts looks like this

```
select  
   vrsta.NAZIV
   ,isnull(sum(prod.prod_mpci),0) as prod_MPCI
   ,isnull(sum(isnull(mal_MPCI,0) + (vel_kol * isnull(mal_MPC,vel_VPC))),0) as lager_mpci
   ,isnull(sum(vel_NCI),0)+isnulL(sum(mal_NCI),0) as lager_nci
   ,sum(   case 
            when isnull(vel_KOL,0)+isnull(mal_KOL,0) > isnull(prod.prod_kol,0) and isnull(dzn.dzn,'2010-01-01') < @dzu
                    then ((isnull(vel_KOL,0)+isnull(mal_KOL,0))-isnull(prod.prod_kol,0)) * isnull(mal_MPC,vel_VPC)
                    else 0 end
            ) as visak_MPC
   ,sum(   case 
            when isnull(vel_KOL,0)+isnull(mal_KOL,0) > isnull(prod.prod_kol,0) and isnull(dzn.dzn,'2010-01-01') < @dzu
                    then ((isnull(vel_KOL,0)+isnull(mal_KOL,0))-isnull(prod.prod_kol,0)) * isnull(mal_NC,vel_NC)
                    else 0 end
            ) as visak_MPC
    ,sum(   case 
            when isnull(vel_KOL,0)+isnull(mal_KOL,0) <= isnull(prod.prod_kol,0) 
                    then ((isnull(vel_KOL,0)+isnull(mal_KOL,0))-isnull(prod.prod_kol,0)) * isnull(mal_MPC,vel_VPC)
                    else 0 end
            ) as manjak_MPC

    ,sum(   case 
            when isnull(vel_KOL,0)+isnull(mal_KOL,0) <= isnull(prod.prod_kol,0) 
                    then ((isnull(vel_KOL,0)+isnull(mal_KOL,0))-isnull(prod.prod_kol,0)) * isnull(mal_NC,vel_NC)
                    else 0 end
            ) as manjak_NC
```

Comment: Well, why are you using so many `isnull()` functions? Your application should be able to deal with `NULL` just fine, or perhaps you can avoid this by not allowing `NULL` in the first place. NULL is not the same thing as 0, but if you're going to treat it that way, it may as well.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I do calculations (+,-,*) inside TSQL but my tables are mostly Left Outer Joined and I have many nulls

Comment: Well there is no magic setting that turns all NULL values into zeroes, sorry.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thanx on that, I was hoping that I can set ANSII NULL param but looks like it ANSII NULL is not in common whit my problem

Comment: @Closers why vote to close  ?

Comment: ANSI_NULLS considers how NULL values are evaluated (e.g. WHERE col = NULL vs. WHERE col IS NULL). It has nothing to do with how NULL float values might be coerced into becoming zero.

Comment: Because you're asking for some functionality that allows you to be lazy but doesn't exist. When a question can be answered with "no" it shouldn't be a question IMHO.

Comment: Can you explain how visak_MPC/manjak_MPC are different? Also how does your query have two aliases called visak_MPC?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what to tell you here fella. Either don't allow the nulls and set a default value to zero or create a view to handle your `ISNULL` problem so that you don't have to add them in the sproc. I don't see the SQL team adding an `ISNULL` across an entire query functionality as most would not find use in this.

Comment: If you show the whole query you might get some help collapsing some of that logic. There is a lot of redundancy there that I suspect isn't required (but I can't know for sure since everything else - FROM, WHERE, etc. is missing).

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thanks a lot on trying to help, Ill show Full source immediate when I got finished my work, That is way there is bugs. I start writing query and saw where it is going and than I stooped and start searching for help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is no way to tell SQL Server to treat all NULL float values as zero. You will have to surround these expressions with [`ISNULL()` or, better yet IMHO, `COALESCE()`](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2689/deciding-between-coalesce-and-isnull-in-sql-server/). You can do this in a view so you don't have to repeat it in every query.

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar query showing a TON of encapsulating ISNULL statements. I need the null values to represent items that have not been touched (as many columns required distinct identifiers for alterations). I tried a million different things to get around it and in the end just ended up with an annoyingly long code laced with a bunch of ISNULLs. The important thing about the 'annoyingly long coded laced with a bunch of ISNULLs' is that it works perfect for me every time. I would suggest just finding a pattern to using them to clean up the look of the code and make it easier to navigate in general.

As far as the suggestion to use COALESCE, I wouldn't suggest it depending on the amount of records you are trying to return. I have read over and over again that COALESCE can cause a  hit to performance, though there are some benefits.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7408893/isnull-vs-coalesce
http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic832742-392-5.aspx#bm1352397

Comment: All of the things you've read over and over again point to performance differential *theories* with no actual data to back them up. Have you [read this link](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2689/deciding-between-coalesce-and-isnull-in-sql-server/), where I actually do performance tests, and also explain the many other benefits?

Answer (score 1):

Dump `isnull`s into an inner query and use them outside maybe to avoid multiple `isnull`s?

```
SELECT A 
FROM (SELECT ISNULL (A, 0) FROM TABLEA) A
...
```